# Help with simple algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone please explain what to do with x in the  following equation, I have not done algebra for a long time so a bit lost:
   $$f(x)= -5 x^5 + 69 x^2 - 47$$

Comment: What do you mean "calculate the equation"?

Comment: calculate what about it?

Comment: sorry, this is the problem I am trying to solve:           Implement the mathematical function f(x) = -5 x5 + 69 x2 - 47 as a Python function. Then use Python to compute the function values f(0), f(1), f(2), and f(3). Enter the maximum of these four numbers.                                     I am just lost as to how to write the code as I don't understand the equation

Comment: I think this question doesn't belong here. I, at least, have no pale idea what a Python function is. That sounds like computing/programming stuff.

Comment: @DonAntonio the question is based on algebra, how can I create an programming function  if I have no idea what it is supposed to do

Comment: But you know what a Python function is, don't you @PadraicCunningham ? Then you're ahead of me...

Comment: It is amazing how people will take the time to moan about your question instead of actually trying to be productive and help. As the saying goes "If you have noting useful to say maybe best to say nothing at all"

Comment: @littleO, I had no problem writing the function, I was just unsure what to do with x. As I said in my question I have not done any algebra for a very long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given:

$$f(x)= -5 x^5 + 69 x^2 - 47$$

We have:

- $f(0) = -5(0)^5 + 69 (0)^2 - 47 = -47$
- $f(1) = -5(1)^5 + 69 (1)^2 - 47 = 17$
- $f(2) = -5(2)^5 + 69 (2)^2 - 47 = 69$
- $f(3) = -5(3)^5 + 69 (3)^2 - 47 = -641$

Comment: @Amotzi, thanks, so just replace x  with  value of x in f(x)?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Correct, anywhere you see an $x$, you substitute the value and then do the math operations, like exponents and then add/subtract. Regards

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: You might want to check out a [*CAS*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems) and some are online, so you don't have to figure out how to code it. You should also upvote and/or accept answers that are helpful. Regards

Comment: @Amotzi Thanks again.

Comment: I will, thanks again

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: You are very welcome! Regards

Comment: You were busy here today! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks. Hope you are having a great day! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(x): return -5*x**5 + 69*x**2 - 47
```